# How to copy a file, recreating the directory structure, using python?

Tags: python, copy

src = `Folder1/Folder2/file1`
(edit: Folder1 has other files and folders as well)

dst = `Folder3`

After copying the file, I want to have
`Folder3/Folder1/Folder2/file1`

I think shutil.copy doesn't recreate the folders and `shutil.copytree` is only for folders (edit: I could have copied folder directly if there weren't other files as well).

Comment: Loop through, create the folders, then create the file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
src = "Folder1/Folder2/file1"
dst = "Folder3"+src
dstfolder = os.path.dirname(dst)
if not os.path.exists(dstfolder):
    os.makedirs(dstfolder)
shutil.copy(src,dst)
```

Comment: nit: `os.path.join` instead of `+`

Answer (score 1):

If your Folder1 contains Folder2 and Folder2 contains file1, what you can do is to copy Folder1 into Folder3 using `shutil`. When you do this, everything in Folder1 will be copied to Folder3 as well.

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree("C:/Users/Desktop/Folder1", "C:/Users/Desktop/Folder3/Folder1")
```

The result:

```
Folder3/Folder1/Folder2/file1
```

Make sure you put `Folder1` after `Folder3` at the destination as above:`Folder3/Folder1")`

Comment: Yes, that was a problem. I had other files in Folder1 which I didn't want to get into Folder3.

Comment: @PiyushRoutray in your OP, before the edit, you didn't mention this. You wanted this result: `Folder3/Folder1/Folder2/file1` and that's exactly what my answer gave you. So, your real question is how NOT to copy some of the files in Folder1. That's a completely different question from the original.

Comment: Yes, that is why I have edited the question now. Sorry for the confusion.
However, I had mentioned shutil.copytree was not the solution for my problem.
Thanks for taking time to answer the question, anyway! Cheers.